# PieChart: how to properly fix unreadable tooltip?

Tags: html, css, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts API v44 and I found something that looks like a bug. At the legend, when name of the entry is too long you can see a tooltip with this name. But in Firefox under Fedora it gets unreadable because the font color and background color are the same: [image: screenshot from FF on Fedora]

I decided to use CSS for that, like this: `.goog-tooltip { color: white; }` and it did the trick, but later I found out that now it got broken on my Mac: [image: screenshot from Mac]

I tried `.goog-tooltip { color: white; background-color: black; }` but it changes background not of the tooltip itself but his borders.

How to customize font/background colors to make tooltips readable everywhere?

If you need a source code: [HTML](https://github.com/php-coder/mystamps/blob/dcf5459b99d8ca4aaecb853a308c686232785911/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/collection/info.html), [JS](https://github.com/php-coder/mystamps/blob/dcf5459b99d8ca4aaecb853a308c686232785911/src/main/javascript/collection/info.js), [CSS](https://github.com/php-coder/mystamps/blob/dcf5459b99d8ca4aaecb853a308c686232785911/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/static/styles/main.css#L90-L93)

Comment: I think the class you're looking for is `div.google-visualization-tooltip {blah:blah}`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options, see following example charts...

**chart 0**
You can use the `tooltip.textStyle` [configuration option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options)
However, this only lets you style the text with the following options, no background...

```
color: <string>,
fontName: <string>,
fontSize: <number>,
bold: <boolean>,
italic: <boolean>
```

**chart 1**
you can provide your own HTML/CSS by providing a tooltip column in the data

`data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}});`

and setting `tooltip.isHtml: true` in the options

For more info, see [Customizing HTML content](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#customizing-html-content)...

**Examples...**

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    // data table
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',       2],
      ['Commute',   2],
      ['Watch TV',  2],
      ['Sleep',     7]
    ]);

    // chart 0
    new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart0')).draw(data, {
      title: 'chart 0',
      tooltip: {
        textStyle: {
          color: 'deeppink',
          fontName: 'Verdana',
          fontSize: 16,
          bold: true,
          italic: true
        }
      }
    });

    // build tooltip column
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}});
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      data.setValue(i, 2,
        '<div class="goog-tooltip"><div class="goog-tooltip-task">' +
        data.getValue(i, 0) + '</div><div class="goog-tooltip-value">' +
        data.getValue(i, 1) + '</div></div>'
      );
    }

    // chart 1
    new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart1')).draw(data, {
      title: 'chart 1',
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```css
.goog-tooltip {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

.goog-tooltip-task {
  color: cyan;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.goog-tooltip-value {
  color: gold;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart0"></div>
<div id="piechart1"></div>
```